# How to work with dataTable?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

My given problem is follow:

I have an object with x columns and every column has y values. I must now bring this into Excel.

I found a snippet in which a datatable can be exported easily. So I will bring my object to a datatable. How can I do this?

Language is C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely certain I know what you're trying to do. I assume you want to create a DataTable and load your existing object into it. Assuming your class looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Column1 {get;set;}
    public DateTime Column2 {get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

and assuming you have a list of them you want to copy into a DataTable, here's how:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (var o in _myObjectList) {
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = o.ID;
    dr["Column1"] = o.Column1;
    dr["Column2"] = o.Column2;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: That is a good way, but also exactly my problem:
I don't know the coloums at the beginning.
I have x objects.
And each object has y values.

So e.g. sometimes i have 2 coloums with 500 and 1000 values, sometimes I have 5 coloums in which each can have his own value count.

Comment: Is this a one off export or a set spreadsheet which is diverse?

Instead of addressing by dr["column1"] you can address by dr[0] and you can also foreach the columns that are available.  if you have patterns you can exploit in the excel I suggest you do so.

Comment: If you want your problem solved, you'll have to describe it. Edit your question with this information and any other information necessary to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the fields of the object and add the columns to the DataTable:

```
private bool IsNullableType(Type theType)
{
    return (theType.IsGenericType && theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)));
}


// Create the columns based on the data in the album info - get by reflection
var ai = new <your object without data>;
Type t = ai.GetType();

this.dataTable.TableName = t.Name;

foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
{
    var columnSpec = new DataColumn();
    // If nullable get the underlying type
    Type propertyType = p.PropertyType;
    if (IsNullableType(propertyType))
    {
        var nc = new NullableConverter(propertyType);
        propertyType = nc.UnderlyingType;
    }
    columnSpec.DataType = propertyType;
    columnSpec.ColumnName = p.Name;
    this.dataTable.Columns.Add(columnSpec);
}

this.dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Then to add a row to the table:

```
var info = new <your object with data>;
// Add by reflection
Type t = info.GetType();
var row = new object[t.GetProperties().Length];

int index = 0;
foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
{
    row[index++] = p.GetValue(info, null);
}

this.dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
```